# Drupal 7 pass variable to same view

Tags: php, drupal, view

Here's what I am trying to accomplish, first I'll describe my set up.

1. Using latest versions of Drupal core, and Views
2. Have a custom module i made that has a table that i have described to Views

Now with that I am trying to make a page where the user will select an account id, when they click the link it will bring up a list of calls associated with that account id. How can this be accomplished in Views? Let me know if I'm providing enough details, this is my first post so go easy on me..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you edit some view under "Advanced" you have "contextual filters". Those are filters that come from "outside world". If you have a page view (display) then those filters are passed as url parameters. And if you embed view or you are just getting view's results you can pass them as parameters.
So, that account id should be that filter and you should pass it somehow.